# When converting CIImage to CGImage, size is not maintained

Tags: swift2

[enter image description here][1]I am applying brightness and contrast to an image. But the output image is not the same size in comparing input image. The output image is cropped by both left and right side but I want input and output image will be same size. Code is given below...

```
let aCGImage = image?.CGImage;
self.aCIImage = CIImage(CGImage: aCGImage!)
self.context = CIContext(options: nil);
self.contrastFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls");
self.contrastFilter.setDefaults()
self.contrastFilter.setValue(self.aCIImage, forKey: "inputImage")

self.contrastFilter.setValue(1.5, forKey: "inputContrast")
self.contrastFilter.setValue(0.1, forKey: "inputBrightness")
let cgimg = self.context.createCGImage(self.contrastFilter.outputImage!, fromRect: self.contrastFilter.outputImage!.extent)

self.newUIImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg!)
```

My input image is normal simulator photo library default image and output image is given below...
Output Image[After add contrast and brightness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMNDr.jpg)

Comment: It would be great, if you provide example of input and output images so we can clearly see what's the problem.

Comment: My post is edited.. please check

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, why your image is cropped, but to maintain size you should specify scale when converting CGImage to UIImage:

```
self.newUIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg, 
                          scale: image.scale, 
                          orientation: image.imageOrientation)
```

It's Swift 3 code, but Swift 2 will be very similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still I have same problem.